# Mono command line program dies with "trace trap" message and nothing else

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monomac

I have a command line Mono application running on the Mac (OSX Lion) and it dies misteriously with the following message:

```
[1]    53342 trace trap  "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/bin/mono" --debug  

read: -p: no coprocess
```

This is running the app from MonoDevelop.

Anyone has any idea what is happening and how I can fix this? (or how I can try to figure out what it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the issue was that there was code like this in the app:

```
#if DEBUG
    Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

The application was being compiled in **Debug** and I was running the app like this:

```
mono Cli.exe
```

And when the interpreter found this piece of code, there was no debugger available when the **trap signal** was sent. While on **Windows** a dialog is opened asking you if you want to debug the app, on **MacOS** the application just commits suicide. The fix was to not execute this code if running on a Mac (or running the app inside of GDB).

Answer (score 1):

Neither how to fix it, nor how to figure out what it is, but to isolate the problem:

- Run it outside MonoDevelop. If it works, report a bug to MonoDevelop.
- Run it outside MonoDevelop with the latest version of Mono (2.11.3). If it still fails, file a bug to Mono.
- (If you have access to a Linux box, try there too because it may be a bug in Mono that only affects Mac platform.)

Bugs are filed in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: In the end it wasn't a Mono bug, just some *smart* code that doesn't work in the mac the same way it works on windows.